# Is embedding Google My Maps possible in react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, maps, react-native-maps

In the documentation, I noticed that the `provider` prop of `MapView` component only takes `google` or `null`. But I want to put this [custom-made map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1_Q9L3i3JRoAop8MVj8_DHNE3hQdtA6Q&ll=24.012091558135854%2C90.80401649999999&z=12) instead of the normal google maps.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to embed Google My Maps in react-native-maps. Google My Maps is a web-based application, and react-native-maps is a native library for iOS and Android. This means that Google My Maps cannot be embedded in a react-native app.

Comment: In that case, I should be able to use KML file to draw the My Maps legends on the react-native-map right?